# Finding totals in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using the tableau superstores dataset in which I'm interested in the fields:

- `Sales`
- `Region`
- `Sub-category` (sub-category of product).

I wanted to find the bottom three sub categories in terms of sales. So I created a calculated field `Bottom three` using the formula `RANK(SUM([Sales]),'asc') <= 3`.I got this viz :
[Bottom three sales.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zeW4.png)

Now I wanted to display the sum of sales of the bottom three sub-categories in the dashboard. How do I find this? I'm quite new to tableau and visualisation and I'm not sure how to do this. I tried displaying a table with

- Rows : Bottom three
- Columns : Categories
- Cells : Sales

I tried using *Total* in analytics tab on each row, but I'm getting an error saying can't apply total to a discrete value.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the total of the bottom 3 use 2 calculated fields:

```
IF RANK(SUM([Sales]),'asc') <= 3 THEN SUM([Sales]) END
```

Then WINDOW_SUM that field. Assuming you call if Bottom3Sales:

```
WINDOW_SUM([Bottom3Sales])
```

Put this field on the Detail shelf, then you can show the total of the bottom 3 in the chart title.

Comment: Thanks! it worked :) I'm just curious, is it possible to display a table with the above value and the sum of sales of remaining sub-categories in the dashboard? Or is it possible to represent these values as percentages ? I tried calculating percentage using the above calculated subfields like this : ```WINDOW_SUM([Bottom3SalesField])/SUM(WINDOW_SUM([OtherSalesField])+ WINDOW_SUM([Bottom3SalesField]))```. But I'm getting an error saying an aggregation cannot be aggregated further.

Comment: It's possible to represent these as %s. SUM(WINDOW_SUM) will throw and an error. Remove the SUM() part.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I'm getting a hang of it now. Thanks.